# php: current_timestamp for database field?

Tags: php, timestamp

i'm trying to add a database field called "lastLogin" which should populate each time someone will log in.
there's an error when trying to add the field:

```
#1294 - Invalid ON UPDATE clause for 'lastLogin' column
```

i'm not sure what's wrong - i'm having the following settings in phpmyadmin:

```
field: lastlogin
type: date
standard: none
attribute: on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

any idea what's wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your field type is set to **date** should be **timestamp** or **datetime**.

> The DATETIME type is used when you
> need values that contain both date and
> time information. MySQL retrieves and
> displays DATETIME values in
> 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The
> supported range is '1000-01-01
> 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type has a range of
> '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
> '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. It has
> varying properties, depending on the
> MySQL version and the SQL mode the
> server is running in. These properties
> are described later in this section.

Comment: According to MySQl site if add date and time to a date field it will only store the date: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html